# WebApplication to Delete file in Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, sharepoint

I am trying to delete a file in Sharepoint from my ASP.NET web application.
For which i have added List.asmx web reference which has Delete attachment method. This method has to be passed with three parameters.

```
   DeleteAttachment(String ListName,String ListItemID, String url);
```

If my file location is below

```
   http://example.com/sites/xxx/xxx/xxx/Shared Documents/yyy/zzz/Review comments_docx.doc
```

What would be the ListName, ListItemID, url.

Below is my code. Can anyone suggest also correct if i am doing anything wrong.

```
    wsLists.Lists objList = new wsLists.Lists();
                    objList.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariablesBO.UserID, GlobalVariablesBO.Password, GlobalVariablesBO.Domain);
                    objList.Url = string.Concat("http://example.com/sites/xxx/xxx/xxx/_vti_bin/lists.asmx");
                    string url = Convert.ToString(item.GetDataKeyValue("SharePointURL"));
                    objList.DeleteAttachment("Shared Documents", "3", url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UpdateListItems(String ListName, XMLNode updates)
```

is a actual method to delete a document in sharepoint.